# How load csv separate by ; in spark using scala?

Tags: csv, apache-spark

How i load a csv separate by ";" now I'm using this function by don't works correctly.

```
val accidentesDF=sqlContext.read.format("csv")
        .option("header", "true")
          .load("src/main/resources/TABLA_ACCVICT_2013.csv");
```

Comment: You should add the delimiter option in the chain: `.option("delimiter", ";")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
val accidentesDF=sqlContext.read.format("csv")
        .option("header", "true")
          .load("src/main/resources/TABLA_ACCVICT_2013.csv", Map("delimiter"->";"));
```